# How to call to non-static parent function from within child function in Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have difficulties in understanding how to pass parent object to child. 
In Qt, I have a MainWindow class and a `DoSomething()` function. Then I created a Job object within MainWindow and tried to call DoSomething within Job's `DoItNow()` function. But I just don't know how to do it.

MainWindow.h

```
class Job;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    int value;
    void DoSomething();

  private:
  Job *job;
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "job.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    job = new Job(this);   // passing this pointer to child
}

void MainWindow::DoSomething() {  // do something }
```

Job.h

```
class Job : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
    void DoItNow();

  public:
    explicit CDMcommand(QObject *parent = 0);
}
```

Job.cpp

```
#include "job.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Job::Job(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  // some setups
  parent->value = 0;    // this is not working
}

void Job::DoItNow()
{
  parent->DoSomething();  // What is the pointer to MainWindow instance?
}
```

- How to access non-static public register in *parent?
- How to pass *parent to function in job instance?

Comment: In `Qt` you generally do this using signals and slots.

Comment: What does `c#` have to do with the question?

Comment: QObject does not have a public field called "value", nor does it have a method named "DoSomething". Those are things that you have defined in your MainWindow class. to access them, "parent" must be declared to be an instance of MainWindow, not QObject.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question. I wanted to create an object Job in MainWindow and though one of Job's function to call for MainWindow's function. What is the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I missunderstand the question, but I think you are a bit confused about inheritance. Your `Job` is a child class of `QObject` and `MainWindow` indirectly inherits also form `QObject`, but there is no direct relation between `MainWindow` and `Job`. I am not too familiar with Qts signal and slot mechanism, which is probably the way to go here, but maybe I can offer you a different solution:

```
Job::Job(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  // some setups
  parent->value = 0;    // this is not working
}
```

This is not working, because `QObject` has no member called `value`. If you can live with `Job`s constructor not taking a `QObject*` as parameter, then just declare a

```
MainWindow* parentWindow;
```

as a private member in `Job` and change the constructor to

```
Job::Job(MainWindow *parentWindow) : QObject(parentWindow)
{
  // some setups
  parentWindow->value = 0;    // this will work now
}
```

then also

```
void Job::DoItNow()
{
  parentWindow->DoSomething();  
}
```

will work without problems.

Comment: That is global variable way? parentWindow is in one block is a parameter, in another is a global variable. No way that passes serious code review.

Comment: @AlexanderVX there is no global variable. If you read it carefully, I proposed to declare `parentWindow` **inside** the `Job` class. However I will edit to remove any ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

> How can I call the Qt 'parent' object method from the 'child'
>    object method?

The safe and simple way to do it:

```
void Job::DoItNow()
{
   // first evaluate the pointer: is that of type we expect?
   MainWindow* pMainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent());
   if (pMainWindow)
       pMainWindow->DoSomething();  // MainWindow::DoSomething must be exposed to class Job
}
```

But of course making two classes dependent on each other too much is a violation of OOP principles: these two objects become tightly coupled now. And there is already a good suggestion in comments: use an explicit signal-slot mechanism for that or providing the interface to interact between decoupled objects.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question. I wanted to create an object Job in MainWindow and though one of Job's function to call for MainWindow's function. What is the correct way of doing so?

Comment: The one I posted. But still think about signal-slot. We do both. We do the one I posted when we are lazy.